# Another Domain Under My Domain

Tags: domains

Say my domain is foo.com and there is another domain bar.com. When people go to, say, xyz.foo.com - I want them to see bar.com. Is this possible to configure somehow. I think I've seen an option like this for some SaaS systems, but I can't recall which. This would be something done for white labeling, etc.

Comment: White labeling requires the cooperation of the site being white labeled.   The site has to be configured to serve up different logos, contact info, and any other differences.   Yes, it also has to be served from a different URL, but doing that is one of the easier things that need to change.

Answer (score 1):

Use a CNAME record in your DNS zone file:

```
xyz.foo.com.        CNAME  bar.com.
```

Remember, MX and NS records cannot point to a CNAME. And your CNAME must always point to a domain, not an IP. Once you do this the alias "bar.com" cannot be used in any other resource records (like MX).

Comment: I like your answer, but I'm a bit confused about your last sentence.  `A` records never involve aliases, they always involve an IP address, so I'm not sure why you imply that a domain could be used in an `A` record somehow.